# Material UI - Responsive Drawer

Tags: reactjs, mobile, responsive-design, material-design, material-ui

Does anyone know how to, or know of any examples of how to create a reactive `Appbar` and `Drawer`?

It needs to be able to dynamically un-dock the drawer and hide when the browser is small and dock the drawer when larger, preferably dynamically like the Material UI site already does: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-drawer/

Comment: You can use material-ui-responsive-drawer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-responsive-drawer Example: https://tarikhuber.github.io/material-ui-responsive-drawer/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could listen for screen size changes in componentWillMount like this, I'm sure there are better methods but this works.

```
toggleOpenDrawer = () => {
    if (!this.state.mobile) {
        return;
    }
    this.setState({
        open: !this.state.open
    })
}

setSmall = () => {
    this.setState({open: false, docked: false, mobile: true})
}

setLarge = () => {
    this.setState({open: true, docked: true, mobile: false})
}

componentWillMount() {
  const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)');
  if (mediaQuery.matches) {
    this.setLarge()
  } else {
    this.setSmall()
  }
  mediaQuery.addListener((mq) => {
    if (mq.matches) {
      this.setLarge()
    } else {
      this.setSmall()
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 17):

For those who're working with material-UI V1 and higher, using [breakpoints](https://material-ui.com/layout/breakpoints/) is the best way to make responsive layouts.

Breakpoints:

- xs, extra-small: 0px or larger
- sm, small: 600px or larger
- md, medium:    960px or larger
- lg, large: 1280px or larger
- xl, xlarge: 1920px or    larger

So, for changing React rendering tree you should pass different breakpoint parameter value into `breakpoints.up()` in the JSS:

```
navIconHide: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      display: 'none',
    },
  },
  toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      position: 'relative',
    },
  },
```

The whole [Drawer source code](https://material-ui.com/demos/drawers/) follows below.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Hidden from '@material-ui/core/Hidden';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import { mailFolderListItems, otherMailFolderListItems } from './tileData';

const drawerWidth = 240;

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    height: 430,
    zIndex: 1,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    position: 'relative',
    display: 'flex',
    width: '100%',
  },
  appBar: {
    position: 'absolute',
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    },
  },
  navIconHide: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      display: 'none',
    },
  },
  toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      position: 'relative',
    },
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
  },
});

class ResponsiveDrawer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    mobileOpen: false,
  };

  handleDrawerToggle = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({ mobileOpen: !state.mobileOpen }));
  };

  render() {
    const { classes, theme } = this.props;

    const drawer = (
      <div>
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        <Divider />
        <List>{mailFolderListItems}</List>
        <Divider />
        <List>{otherMailFolderListItems}</List>
      </div>
    );

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <AppBar className={classes.appBar}>
          <Toolbar>
            <IconButton
              color="inherit"
              aria-label="Open drawer"
              onClick={this.handleDrawerToggle}
              className={classes.navIconHide}
            >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" noWrap>
              Responsive drawer
            </Typography>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <Hidden mdUp>
          <Drawer
            variant="temporary"
            anchor={theme.direction === 'rtl' ? 'right' : 'left'}
            open={this.state.mobileOpen}
            onClose={this.handleDrawerToggle}
            classes={{
              paper: classes.drawerPaper,
            }}
            ModalProps={{
              keepMounted: true, // Better open performance on mobile.
            }}
          >
            {drawer}
          </Drawer>
        </Hidden>
        <Hidden smDown implementation="css">
          <Drawer
            variant="permanent"
            open
            classes={{
              paper: classes.drawerPaper,
            }}
          >
            {drawer}
          </Drawer>
        </Hidden>
        <main className={classes.content}>
          <div className={classes.toolbar} />
          <Typography noWrap>{'You think water moves fast? You should see ice.'}</Typography>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ResponsiveDrawer.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  theme: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(ResponsiveDrawer);
```

Answer (score 5):

In **MUI v5**, you can display 2 `Drawers` in different screen sizes. The [permanent](https://mui.com/components/drawers/#permanent-drawer) `Drawer` is always visible in the larger screen. In small screen, you can remove it easily using [responsive values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69221863/9449426) in `sx` prop:

```
<Drawer
  variant="permanent"
  open
  sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', sm: 'block' } }}
>
```

And show a [temporary](https://mui.com/components/drawers/#temporary-drawer) `Drawer` that can be opened or closed. The temporary one doesn't affect the layout since it appears on top which is suitable in mobile view.

```
<Drawer
  variant="temporary"
  open={mobileOpen}
  onClose={handleDrawerToggle}
  sx={{ display: { xs: 'block', sm: 'none' } }}
>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

### Reference

- https://mui.com/components/drawers/#responsive-drawer

Answer (score 0):

I agree with NearHuscarl, in case you want to use media queries, should be smt like this:

```
 sx={{
      ['@media (min-width: 0px)']: {
        display: 'block',
      },
      ['@media (min-width: 600px)']: {
        display: 'none',
      },
      '& .MuiDrawer-paper': { boxSizing: 'border-box', width: drawerWidth },
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useMediaQuery` [hook](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-use-media-query/#basic-media-query).

```
const matches = useMediaQuery("(min-width:768px)");

<Drawer
  variant={matches ? "permanent" : "temporary"}
  ...
</Drawer>
```